# Invalid Component Element in React.JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've been going through a react.js tutorial, with a simple hello world example. I can't find a reason why the following shouldn't work, but I keep getting this error.

```
Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: React.render(): Invalid component element.
```

I have the following code. It seems to work if I do React.createElement, but not for the JSX elements.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://fb.me/react-0.13.3.js"></script>
    <script src="https://fb.me/JSXTransformer-0.13.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/jsx">
        document.body.onload = function(){
            console.log("shuff")
            var HelloWorld = React.createClass({
                render: function(){
                    return <div>Hello, Ian Shuff!</div>;
                }
            });

            React.render( new HelloWorld(), document.getElementById("test"))
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="test"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You should pass to render `<HelloWorld />`, not `new HelloWorld()`

```
React.render(<HelloWorld />, document.getElementById("test"))
```

[`Example`](http://jsbin.com/tahosibeju/1/edit?html,output)

[`jsx-in-depth`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html)

Or you can use `React.createElement`, like so

```
React.render(React.createElement(HelloWorld, null), document.getElementById("test"))
```

[`Example`](http://jsbin.com/leguxenozu/1/edit?html,output)