# Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: React.render(): Invalid component element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm a react newbie

and I'm Creating a simple class and function and rendering to the body.

However,

I get an `Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: React.render(): Invalid component element.`

```
<script src="https://fb.me/react-0.13.3.js"></script>
<script src="https://fb.me/JSXTransformer-0.13.3.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/jsx">

    var HelloWorld = React.createClass({
        render: function() {
            return <div>Hello, world!</div>;
        }
    });

    React.render(new HelloWorld(), document.body);

</script>


<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas on what is wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invalid Component Element in React.JS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30275793/invalid-component-element-in-react-js)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Change `React.render(new HelloWorld(), document.body);` to `React.render(React.createElement(HelloWorld), document.body);` and it should work.  `The React.render` function expects a `ReactElement` which you can create via `React.createElement`.

You can see the docs here along with some other useful functions: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html

Answer (score 17):

use `<HelloWorld/>` instead of `new HelloWorld()`

Comment: This helped me out, I had `ReactDOM.render('<App />', document.getElementById('app'));` but needed to have `ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));` - no quotes around the `<App />`

Comment: I have it without quotes, and still get the error :/

Answer (score 0):

Writting the render method of your component like this will launch the same Error:

```
...
render: function() {
  return      //you need "return <div>" for this to work.
    <div> 
      <h4>MyComponent message</h4>
    </div>;
}
```

The shown code will trigger the same error because there is now element next to the return (you shouldn't break the line there).