# Webpack, ReactJS - Uncaught Error: ReactDOM.render(): Invalid Component element

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack

I am getting the `Uncaught Error: ReactDOM.render(): Invalid Component element` in `wepack:///...invariant.js`.
Here is my `package.json` and `webpack.config.js`:

```
{
  "name": "githubOauth",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "webpack.config.js",
  "scripts": {
    "setup:init": "npm-run-all --parallel start:db setup:db setup:ssl",
    "setup:ssl": "hz create-cert && mv *.pem config/tls",
    "setup:db": "./config/rethinkdb/setup.sh",
    "start:db": "rethinkdb",
    "start": "webpack && node server.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.13.2",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.5",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.13.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.11.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.5.0",
    "npm-run-all": "^2.3.0",
    "webpack": "^1.9.10",
    "webpack-bundle-tracker": "0.0.51",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^1.5.4",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@horizon/client": "^2.0.0",
    "@horizon/server": "^2.0.0",
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "react": "^15.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.3.1",
    "react-router": "^2.7.0"
  }
}
```

and

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: ["./src/app.js"],

    output: {
        filename: "dist/js/bundle.js",
        sourceMapFilename: "dist/js/bundle.map"
    },
    externals: {
        React: 'react'
    }, 

    devtool: '#source-map',
    resolve: {
      fallback: './node_modules'
    },
    resolveLoader: {
        root: [
            path.join(__dirname, "node_modules")
          ],
       fallback: './node_modules',
       modulesDirectories: [
          './node_modules'
      ]
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { 
                test: /\.json$/, 
                loader: 'json-loader' 
            },
            {
                loader: 'babel',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            }
        ]
    },
    node: {
        console: 'empty',
        fs: 'empty',
        net: 'empty',
        tls: 'empty'
      }
}
```

Here is my console error snapshot:
[image]

Comment: Is it possible you are using a module which is relying on node's net module? Perhaps this is not available to the browser which is why webpack can't resolve it?

Comment: but that error is occurring in a number of files where there is `require` keyword.

Comment: your webpack config is a little funky, are you sure you've got it set up properly? you're targeting node and then trying to load it in a browser, for one thing..

Comment: I am not sure.. I was able to start the server using `npm start` and it is throwing error at runtime.

Comment: @John  I cleaned some stuff from webpack.config.js`.. now getting the error as mentioned in the modified question!

Comment: This is probably an issue w/ a render call somewhere. One example for this error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30275793/invalid-component-element-in-react-js